# Misuse of the term "Initialize"?

Tags: design-patterns, naming

I'm working on a redesign for part of an existing application and I'm having a bit of an issue with the toughest programming problem of all: naming things correctly :)

I have a class (`A`) which can create instances of `B`. Each `A` has an active `B` object.
To activate the object, it calls a method `Initialize` on `B`, passing a reference to itself. `B` will check the state of `A`, subscribe to changes in `A`, etc.

At some point, `A` can decide it no longer needs `B`, at which point `B` goes into a pool of objects that can be reused. A different instance of `A` can decide to pick up the existing `B` object instead of creating one.

When this happens, the `Initialize` method is called again on the existing object `B`.

Now, I have the feeling that this could be confusing because people will probably expect initialization to happen only once. **Is there a better generic term I could use** in this situation? I would also like to introduce a complement of the `Initialize` method, that tells `B` it can stop paying attention to `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you already hit on the term in your description:

> To activate the object, it calls a method Initialize on B, passing a reference to itself.

Activate and Deactivate would be appropriate method names.

Comment: Interestingly enough I'm already using Activate and Deactivate for several other things in the same design. I will have to consider if this will not actually cause more confusion, but I can see how it would be appropriate.

Comment: Ya, the best terms often fall out when you try to describe the concepts in as plain an English as possible. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In similar situations I have used Attach() and Dettach() to represent a transitory connection between objects.

```
bInstance.Attach(this)
```

and later when putting it back in the pool

```
bInstance.Dettach()
```